# 'API Tools Javadoc Proposals' issue in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javadoc

So I was working on eclipse when I received this issue

```
The 'API Tools Javadoc Proposals' proposal computer from the
'org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui' plug-in did not complete normally.
The extension has thrown a runtime exception.
```

This happened directly after I installed Java-8 into eclipse.

Now my understanding that this is a comparability issue so I tried multiple things as shown below, however I still face the same issue

```
1- I have tried help->Check for Updates
```

So it performed some updates normally but the same issue remained as it is

```
2- I have tried help->Install new Software to install JAutodoc
```

So I got the link for their website and installed the latest update I believe, however the same issue remained.

Website:       http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Update link:  http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/update/

As for someone not familiar with this tool, I believe that I might have forgot something. However searching through the internet did not help me.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433918

Like the poster in the bug report, I was able to fix this (in Kepler) by uninstalling everything to do with the Groovy plugin.  After uninstalling the groovy pieces I had to reinstall java 8 support from [this Kepler-specific link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler), and then I was able to reinstall the Groovy plugin using the J8-specific groovy eclipse link in the bug report: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.3-j8

Then once I fixed the compiler compliance level in my project to 1.8, things were working again.

(Took me a while to find how to uninstall things: Help -> Install new software, and then click the little "already installed" link at the bottom.)

From the bug report, it sounds like this bug wouldn't happen in a newer Eclipse (Luna or Mars.)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem today.
I solved it as follow (I have a mac, instructions for other operating systems might differ)

- Open Eclipse
- About Eclipse
- Installation Details
  *Find org.eclipse.pde.api.tool.ui
  *click update.
  Updating the plugin solved my issues. I am not sure if this solution works for everyone but it works for me.